VS Code Mac Maui Error Duplicate PageReference items found Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.7
I have switched a project (Xamarin, iOS, Android) from VS for Mac to VS Code (Mac-Version).
Wehn building I get the error: warning NU1504: Duplicate 'PackageReference' items found. Remove the duplicate items or use the Update functionality to ensure a consistent restore behavior. The duplicate 'PackageReference' items are: Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.7, Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.7. [TargetFramework=net8.0-android] for all TargetFrameworks.
There is no PackageReference in the project. There is only one .csProj-file, in which
net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;
is defined.
Can anybody help out of this?
I have deleted the bin- and obj-folder, restarted. Asked and followed some instructions of ChatGPT, but nothing helped.

From the official document NuGet Warning NU1504, you can try the following solution:


Remove the duplicate items
Use item Update instead of item Include


